# Importing json; Typescript error: Module has no exported member

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to import a .json file into my Angular8 project, but for some reason I keep getting the 'Module has no exported member' error.

I tried to simplify the code, but no result this is what I have.

First I added this in the compilerOptions object (tsconfig.json)
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,

```
// assests/example.json
{
  "name": "Spaghetti",
  "desc": "Vegetarische spaghetti bolgnese",
  "rating": 3.7
}

// recipe component
import { example } from '../../../assets/example.json';

  constructor() {
    console.log(example.name);
  }
```

I keep getting this error:
Module '"@angular/recipe-app/src/assets/example"' has no exported member 'example'.ts(2305)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the import without the brackets around the example. You can use one of the following examples:

```
import example from "../../../assets/example.json";
```

OR

```
import * as example from "../../../assets/example.json";
```

Comment: I've added both (angular 11) and I'm still getting error:

  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "./node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    }

  },

Comment: @olNoy did you set `"resolveJsonModule": true` in the tsconfig.json file?

Comment: Yes. I'm using webstorm. It might be related to the IDE as I was able to build and run the angular application

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this

```
import * as something from '../../../assets/example.json';
```

and then you can refer `something` in your .ts file